# Using WHERE with unknown amount of OR

Tags: c#, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a table with some integer column `A`.

I need to select rows where `A` equals `1` or `2` or `4` (for example), but i don't know how many values i need to compare. I have an array of values as input with unknown amount of values.

I tried this:

`myTable.Where(x=> myArray.Contains(x.A))`

but it doesn't work (i also tried `Any`)

Then i tried to build SQL query with `foreach` cycle and then use `.FromSqlRaw()` but it throws an exception:

> 'FromSqlRaw' or 'FromSqlInterpolated' was called with non-composable SQL and with a query composing over it.

Comment: Replace the array with a `List<string>`.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code you posted. Please show where myTable and myArray are defined, and how the corresponding column types in the database table.

Comment: Please explain, what do you mean by `but it doesn't work`

Comment: It type in myArray (integer or string) same as database?

Comment: you know what? It is working now... i'm not sure maybe converting from array to List was helpful or i have changed something else. Sorry for confusing.

Comment: maybe i should delete the question?